# How to validate for nullable types using json schema validator?

Tags: json, scala, playframework, null, json-schema-validator

I'm using the [play-json-schema-validator](https://github.com/eclipsesource/play-json-schema-validator) and want to set up an integration test with scala in order to check an API's JSON response schema.

Certain fields of the response are nullable and I want to validate for that. So some field can be either a string or null yet it can never be a number.

Playing around on [its playground](http://play-json-schema-validator.herokuapp.com) I want to validate for an array of objects that each object's `name` property is either a string or null.

I came up with this schema:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "title": "Product set",
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "title": "Product",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": ["string", null]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Yet though it validates the string and null case, I now get a false positive for numbers. I was expecting an error for this json, yet it validates:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Red anger"
  },
  {
    "name": null
  },
  {
    "name": 13
  }
]
```

How to declare a field of a type as nullable using schema validator?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Enquote the null in the schema:

```
"type": ["string", "null"]
```

You can read about that in the [json schema validation documentation](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#rfc.section.3.1), i.e.:

> 6.1. Validation Keywords for Any Instance Type
>
> 6.1.1. type
>
> The value of this keyword MUST be either a string or an array. If it is an array, elements of the array MUST be strings and
>   MUST be unique.
>
> String values MUST be one of the six primitive types ("null",
>   "boolean", "object", "array", "number", or "string"), or "integer"
>   which matches any number with a zero fractional part.
>
> An instance validates if and only if the instance is in any of the
>   sets listed for this keyword.

Answer (score 2):

The type attribute of the schema does not accept arrays but only a single type at the time:
**"string", "null"...** and as you pointed out, the types should be strings so instead of null => "null"

If you want to check multiple types for a single field you need to use

**anyOf, oneOf, allOf**

Here is an example working with your input

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "title": "Product set",
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "title": "Product",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "anyOf": [
            {"type":"string"},
            {"type":"null"},
            {"type":"number"}
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```